# Angularjs and Socket.io, impossible to edit a value in my view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

To learn to use AngularJS and NodeJS, I want to create a chatroom... All Angular controllers works fine and I can to send informations to my NodeJS server (with socket.io). But the problem is: When my clientApp receive a socket.on and I change the value of a var in my view it not work... Do you know why ?

View:

```
<!-- Users connected -->
            <div class="row" ng-controller="connectedUsersCtrl">
              <div class="col-md-8"></div>
              <div class="col-md-4" ng-model="connectedUsers">{{connectedUsers}}</div>
            </div>
```

app.js:

```
var chatApp= angular.module('chatApp', []);
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:2901');


chatApp.controller('connectedUsersCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    socket.on("connectedUsers", function(number) {
        console.log("There are " + number + " users.");

        // All work but not this line... ! 
        $scope.connectedUsers = number;

    });

}]);
```

Thanks you for you help.
Best regards,

Edit:
To force the edition, you have to put: $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call a

```
$timeout(function () { $scope.$apply() });
```

or try to make a Javascript Object e.g.

```
$scope.counter = {
    users: 0
};
```

and when you receive event : `$scope.counter.users = number`
then in your view : call `counter.users`

I hope it will solve your problem !